# Cannot get rid of "The system is running in low graphic mode"

Tags: graphics, virtualbox, amd-graphics, kvm-virtualization

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial LTS and can't get rid of this error after trying so many question on almost a dozens of forum. My machine details are:

```
Debian: Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial
System: VT-x/AMD-V, Nested Paging, PAE/NX, KVM Paravirtualization
VirtualBox: Version 5.1.22
VM Display settings: Video memory 12 MB, Remote Desktop Server=Disabled, Video Capture=Disabled
```

.

I've tried almost all the solutions with high votes from last 12 hours.

Please assist.

Comment: This suddenly started happening to me on a 17.04 machine in Virtualbox.  I could never track down the cause. I backed up and reinstalled, and then it worked again.  I hate "reinstall" as an answer, hence posting as a comment.

Comment: The solution I am using for time being as I didn't had time to solve it myself that I've created snapshots. After some work is done and I needed to save settings I would add new snapshot to system. That is how its working for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following the instructions at this link "https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=56159", courtesy of user *claytoncarney*.

At the appearance of the *...low-graphic mode...* message:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> to switch to a command line (`tty` mode)
- Login with password
- `cd /etc/X11`
- `sudo cp xorg.conf.failsafe xorg.conf`
- `sudo service lightdm restart`

I found this worked for Ubuntu 16.04 running inside VBox-6.0 on Windows 7.